# How do I stop gsub from repeating? [Roblox Studio]

Tags: replace, lua, gsub, roblox

I have a string, which has the word "amogus" in it. I use gsub, to replace amogus with

```
"<font color="..red..">".."amogus".."</font>"
```

But everytime I refresh to check for anything else I need to gsub, it thinks that the replaced text needs to be replaced, since it also contains amogus. How can I fix this?
Thanks
-creepersaur

Answer (score 2):

You may solve it with `%f` pattern:

```
local s = "  amo  <>amo<>  "
s = s:gsub("%f[%w>]amo", "<>amo<>")
print(s)  -->   <>amo<>  <>amo<>
```